# Show that $A^2+2A+5I=0$ has a solution if and only if $n$ is even.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I have a real square matrix $A$. I am told to prove that there is $A$ such that $A^2+2A+5I=0$ if and only if $n$ is even. (If $A$ is 6x6, $n=6$)

I honestly have no clue how to start. Maybe I could turn this into a question with minimal polynomial and use $x^2+2x+5$. This polynomial doesn't have a root, and it is making me even more confused. Could someone help? Thank you.

Comment: $x^2+1=0$ doesn't have a real root, yet it is satisfied by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. It is not really that weird that a polynomial with no real roots has a matrix "root".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $n$ is not even then $A$ has a real eigenvalue since that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has an odd degree and hence has a real root.

Hence since the polynomial $x^2+2x+5$ has no real roots, it means that $n$ is even.

Comment: This is a very good hint yet to fully understand it the OP is going to have a very good understanding of roots of characteristic pol, miimal pol. and etc. to complete. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio this is only half of an answer

Comment: @Shalop That doesn't matter. We are allowed to post hints.

Comment: @Arthur sure, but at least say that it’s a hint

Answer (score 4):

Take $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda^2+2\lambda +5=0$ and pick $A \in Mat(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that $$A=\begin{pmatrix} \ Re(\lambda) & -Imm(\lambda) \\ Imm(\lambda) 
 & Re(\lambda) \end{pmatrix} .$$

You can check this works for $n=2$ as the matrix multiplication is the same as complex multiplication and try to generalize  this to $n=2k$ with generic $k$.

This proves that such a matrix exists if $n$ is even. To prove the inverse statement there is the answer upon mine

Comment: I don't understand this. The matrix $\;A\;$ is given...

Comment: I understood there was and iff in his question,so one had to show also the existence of such a matrix in case $n$ is even,while the other implication had already been answered

Answer (score 2):

The condition implies that $(A+I)^2 = -4I_n$. What are the signs of determinants on both sides when $n$ is odd?

Answer (score 0):

If n is even, you may construct the matrix in this way:

we know
$$A^2+2A+5I_n=O\iff(\frac{(A+I)}{2})^2=-I_n$$
then take$$\frac{(A+I)}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1& & & &\\
1&0& & & &\\
 & &0&-1& &\\
 & &1&0& &\\
 & & & &...& \end{pmatrix}
$$
This has a clear geometric meaning.